# Android: adding and removing View programmatically

Tags: android, view, nullpointerexception, android-inflate

I am adding and removing view dynammically, as follows:

## Codes:

```
    view_share_dialog = findViewById(R.id.view_share_coloring);

    case R.id.btn_share_coloring:

        if(btn.isChecked())
        {

            CloseOpenedView(btn);
            AnimUtils.slideToLeft_ColorView(view_share_dialog, mContext);
            view_share_dialog.bringToFront();
            mDrawView.newLine(android.R.color.transparent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "FRONT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            img.bringToFront();
            AnimUtils.slideToRight_ColorView(view_share_dialog, mContext);                  
            mDrawView.newLine(Color.parseColor(allColors[lastSelectedCol]));
            ((RelativeLayout)view_share_dialog.getParent()).removeView(view_share_dialog);

            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "GONE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        break;

// these are the buttons of choices for sharing in the View
public void shareButtonClickable(boolean clickable)
{
    findViewById(R.id.btn_share_copy).setClickable(clickable);  //line 467
    findViewById(R.id.btn_share_email).setClickable(clickable);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_share_facebook_c).setClickable(clickable);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_share_photo_album).setClickable(clickable);
}
```

## Logcat:

```
06-22 01:52:36.571: E/AndroidRuntime(15096): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
06-22 01:52:36.571: E/AndroidRuntime(15096):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-22 01:52:36.571: E/AndroidRuntime(15096):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-22 01:52:36.571: E/AndroidRuntime(15096):    at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3964)
06-22 01:52:36.571: E/AndroidRuntime(15096):    ... 12 more
06-22 01:52:36.571: E/AndroidRuntime(15096): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-22 01:52:36.571: E/AndroidRuntime(15096):    at com.abc.abc.ColoringPageActivity.shareButtonClickable(ColoringPageActivity.java:467)
06-22 01:52:36.571: E/AndroidRuntime(15096):    at com.abc.abc.ColoringPageActivity.onClickToggle_coloring(ColoringPageActivity.java:528)
06-22 01:52:36.571: E/AndroidRuntime(15096):    ... 15 more
```

## Question:

For the first time pressing the `btn_share_coloring` button, the view can be animated from right of screen to the center. And then when the `btn_share_coloring` is pressed again (i.e. unchecked), the view can also be animated from center to the right, with the `Toast` "Gone" can be properly shown. Yet when the user further press again for the btn, a fatal NPE will be resulted.

While the View can be properly being removed, how could the view be inflated again properly?

Thanks!

Comment: line 467 is now newly indicated in the codes above~ it is one of the buttons inside the view

Comment: Looks like you should readd `view_share_dialog`. Something like `((RelativeLayout)view_share_dialog.getParent()).addView(view_share_dialog);`

Comment: i would like to ask since there are buttons inside the view, do i need to add the buttons inside the view one by one apart from the view? or adding the view will together adding all the things inside it?

Comment: If you remove view X and then add it again, it will be back with whatever it contained before.